# Node js sql data not being shown on handlebars when passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I hava a button response on my express-handlebars, when clicked it should execute an sql query and store selected data to an array, the problem is that when I pass the data to the other page handlebars doesn't the data.

```
app.post('/smo_assessment', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id=?', req.body.requestID, function(err, rows, fields){

        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            selectedRequest = rows; 
            res.render('smo_assessment', {assessmentType, data: selectedRequest});
            console.log(selectedRequest);
        }
    });
});
```

But `console.log(selectedRequest)` works and logs the entire row, and when rendering the response 'smo_assessment' handle bars doesn't show the data from selectedRequest.

This is my handlebars.

```
<table class="table table-borderless" id="tbnInfo"">
        <tr>
            <th>Date Requested:</th>
            <td bgcolor="white">{{data.date_requested}}</td>
            <th>Date Needed:</th>
            <td bgcolor="white">{{data.date_needed}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Division:</th>
            <td bgcolor="white">{{data.division}}</td>
            <th>Community:</th>
            <td bgcolor="white">{{data.community}}</td>
        </tr>
</table
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking  ... please explain little more.

Comment: I think selectedRequest is empty when passed to handlebars, but when doing console.log(selectedRequest); it shows all the data.

Comment: Can you show how your handlebar template is trying to consume the provided data?

Comment: @Lekhnath my handlebars is correct, but why?

Comment: I assume `data` is probably an array so do this in your template `data[0].date_requested` instead of `data.date_requested`

Comment: @ Lekhnath thanks.